# List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> to json in asp.net MVC 4?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model like the following :

```
public class GridViewModel
{
    public List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> Rows { get; set; }
    public int FoundItems { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    public string PagingLinks { get; set; }//Contains Html Tags
}
```

`Rows` will fill dynamically in Controllers like the following :

`Rows = [ [Id=1, Name='Name', FullName='FullName'], [Id=2, Name='Name', FullName='FullName'], ... ];`

I wanna convert the Model to JSON for sending through JsonResult.
So, I expect something like the following in my JSON :

```
{ 
   Rows : [ 
            { Id=1, Name='Name', FullName='FullName'}, 
            { Id=2, Name='Name', FullName='FullName'}
          ],
   FoundItems : 123,
   CurrentPage : 1,
   TotalPages : 3,
   ItemsPerPage : 50,
   PagingLinks : '<b>1</b><span>2</span><span>3</span>'
}
```

Could you please guide me, How can I convert the model to JSON ?

Comment: Ever heard about primitive obsession?

Comment: doesn't `this.Json()` in your action method just work?
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504936(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: @Knaģis: No, I've tested

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları: No, I don't heard about it !

Comment: It will be really easier to read your code if you create custom types for your data, instead of deeply nesting the types in BCL.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları: I'm working on a general thing, so I have to have a general model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `List` within `List` made up of `KeyValuePair` looks wrong to me, surely you want:

```
 List<Dict<string,string>>   // Will be serialized correctly by Json.Net
```

Assuming you are correct in wanting `List<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>`, most of this is automatic assuming you're using the Json.Net (Newtonsoft JSON) that is included with MVC4, the structure you're going to get is fairly similar.  It would default to something like:

Help page for [Serializing Collections](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/?topic=html/SerializingCollections.htm)

```
// Assumption: you already know how to use JObject.Convert or one of the other
// serialization/deserialization classes.

{
    Rows : [ 
              {
                  [
                     {"Row1Key1":"Row1Value1"},
                     {"Row1Key2":"Row1Value2"}
                  ]
              },
              {
                  [
                     {"Row2Key1":"Row2Value1"}
                  ]
              }
           ],
    // etc (as in example provided)
```

Your mention of 'Id' has no corresponding data with that value and would be determined by position within the JSON.

If you truly want the ID part, you're going to have to supply a JsonConverter and project the collection out with your own logic (e.g. Id is off by one compared to the index).